# Navigate through entities in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, where-clause

Im having some trouble writting a linq expression using entity framework. I have two related entities. Pago (payments) and Cuota(shares). In Cuota, I have the id_prestamo (loan id).

What I need is to get all the Pago(payments) for one Prestamo(loan). But as i have the Pago related only to Cuota, i have to get the id_prestamo from Cuota. The problem is that I cant navigate throw Cuota like this:

```
Lista_pagos = db.Pago.Where(x => x.Cuota.Prestamo.id_prestamo == prestamo.id_prestamo).ToList();
```

I tried also this expression but it doesnt work either:

```
Lista_pagos = db.Pago.Where(x => x.Cuota.Where(y => y.Prestamo.id_prestamo == prestamo.id_prestamo)).ToList();
```

When I say it doesn´t work is because I cannot compile the application. There must be an error in this place `x.Cuota.Where(y =>` but don´t know how to use the where sentence right. I get this:

[image]

"The delegate does not take 1 argument"

Does anybody know how can i write this expression right?

I attach the entity relationship below.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: "doesn't work". Can you please elaborate? **What** doesn't work? In general, this sort of thing should work, but you don't show very much code or any errors.

Comment: Check now. It´s a syntax problem. But I don´t know whats wrong in the expression. I wish i could use the first one, but I cant navigate the entity like that :/.

Comment: What is the compile error for your first query? Is it prestamo.id_prestamo or Prestamo.id_prestamo for the ID you need? (you're using both)

Comment: Sorry! its prestamo.id_prestamo. As I said, I cant navigate Cuota. When i write x => x.Cuota. I dont get any of the related entities. I just can write where, any, etc. I tried using Include("Prestamo") but still does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your query.

```
db.Pago.Where()
```

...takes a predicate -- a function which returns `bool`.

```
x.Cuota.Where()
```

...returns `IQueryable<Cuota>`

So:

```
db.Pago.Where(x => x.Cuota.Where( ... ))
```

...is invalid code, because `IQueryable<Cuota>` is not `bool`.

I *think* what you actually want is:

```
Lista_pagos = db.Pago.Where(
    x => x.Cuota.Any(y => y.Prestamo.id_prestamo == prestamo.id_prestamo)
).ToList();
```

(Note `Any` instead of `Where`.)

Comment: As I said, I cant navigate Cuota. When i write x => x.Cuota. I dont get any of the related entities. I just can write where, any, etc. I tried using Include("Prestamo") but still does not works.

Comment: What's wrong with the first sample is that Pago -> Cuota is many to many, so you have to treat it like a list, not 1:1.

Comment: You´re right! That was the problem. Im used to Django´s ORM and I´m finding EF a bit more difficult to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You have Cuotas for your Prestamos (by the way, Cuota is Installment, not Share, share is Acción) and you want all the Pagos for a given Prestamo:

```
Lista_Pagos = (from p in Pagos 
                join c in Cuotas 
                on p.Cuota.Cuota_Id equals c.Cuota_Id 
                where c.Prestamo.Prestamo_Id == prestamo.Prestamo_Id
                select p).ToList<Pago>();
```

Comment: Thank you really much for your answer. Im checking which of the two answers suits me better.

Comment: [It's almost always wrong to use `join` in L2E](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).